# Where Logs about User Boot on OSX?

Tags: macos, boot, macbook

My friend installed Yosemite OSX to his Macbook pro. 
For some reason, it is lagging in the booting very much; many others have the same problem in [some Macs](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6608931). 
Mine not in the newest Macbook Air. 
I would like investigate this further. 
**Which log files about booting should I look at?**

I started some user login registering in my own Macbook Air which gives me pieces of information about login each time on the screen. 
I forgot the command. 
This is useful thing to see directly on the screen if there are problems in the startup and booting.

I am at **/var/log/** and I run

```
ls -lt | head
```

and I get

```
total 199016
-rw-r-----@  1 root             admin             1865155 Oct 30 22:15 system.log
-rw-r--r--@  1 root             admin                2246 Oct 30 22:14 accountpolicy.log
-rw-r--r--@  1 root             admin              652335 Oct 30 22:13 commerce.log
-rw-r--r--@  1 masi        staff            38436355 Oct 30 22:13 install.log
-rw-r--r--@  1 root             wheel             4509046 Oct 30 22:08 appfirewall.log
-rw-r-----@  1 root             admin               25067 Oct 30 22:08 authd.log
-rw-r--r--   1 _displaypolicyd  _displaypolicyd     12457 Oct 30 22:08 displaypolicyd.log
-rw-r-----   1 root             admin                3045 Oct 30 22:07 opendirectoryd.log
-rw-r-----@  1 root             admin                3292 Oct 30 22:07 secinitd.log
```

I can run there too

```
ls -t | grep -i boot
```

getting no hits. 
I probably look at wrong locations and wrong things.
The word **boot** is not probably the right thing to search.

**What are the user specific log files about what is happening in the boot?**
The system is waiting much before the user password is even asked. 
So I am not sure if I use right terms here about user specific log files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo dmesg` in terminal.app (It will prompt for password) this should show you the last start-up information

and

```
sudo dmesg | more
```

should give you the output for those messages.